# Comparison of .txt file with table using oracle or sql

Tags: sql-server, toad

I need to compare the data present in extract(.txt file) with data present in table . And wants to find out the mismatches b/w the extract and table

Comment: Import the txt file to a new table and compare the two tables with a query.

Comment: i donot have access to create a new table

Comment: Can you write a .net app?

Comment: it's a testing environment. i Don't think there we can use another software